# how to suppress single and multi-line comments using a regexp?

Tags: java, regex, string

I need do find all multiline comments in a string and replace them with a space (if the comment is in one line) or with a `\n` (if the comment is on more than one line).
for example:

```
int/* one line comment */a;
```

should be changed to:

```
int a;
```

and this:

```
int/* 
more
than one
line comment*/a;
```

should be changed to:

```
int
a;
```

I have one String with all the text and I used this command:

```
file = file.replaceAll("(/\\*([^*]|(\\*+[^*/]))*\\*+/)"," ");
```

where file is the string.

The problem is it finds all multiline comment and I want to separate it to 2 cases.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved using [`Matcher.appendReplacement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement%28java.lang.StringBuffer,%20java.lang.String%29) and [`Matcher.appendTail`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendTail%28java.lang.StringBuffer%29).

```
String file = "hello /* line 1 \n line 2 \n line 3 */"
            + "there /* line 4 */ world";

StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?m)/\\*([^*]|(\\*+[^*/]))*\\*+/").matcher(file);

while (m.find()) {

    // Find a comment
    String toReplace = m.group();

    // Figure out what to replace it with
    String replacement = toReplace.contains("\n") ? "\n" : "";

    // Perform the replacement.
    m.appendReplacement(sb, replacement);
}

m.appendTail(sb);

System.out.println(sb);
```

**Output:**

```
hello 
there  world
```

---

**Note:** If you want to preserve correct line number / columns for all text that is *not* inside comments (good if you want to refer back to the source code in error messages etc) I would recommend doing

```
String replacement = toReplace.replaceAll("\\S", " ");
```

which replaces all non-whitespace with white space. This way `\n` is preserved, and

```
"/* abc */"
```

is replaced by

```
"         "
```